# How to convert the below T-SQL Query ISNULL(NAME,'N/A') to Spark-SQL Equivalent

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

Not able to convert the below T-SQL Query part ISNULL(NAME,'N/A') to Spark-SQL Equivalent

SELECT
ID,
ISNULL(NAME,'N/A') AS NAME,
COMPANY
FROM TEST to

convert the below T-SQL Query part ISNULL(NAME,'N/A') to Spark-SQL Equivalent

SELECT
ID,
ISNULL(NAME,'N/A') AS NAME,
COMPANY
FROM TEST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [isnull()](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/isnull.html) merely returns a boolean stating if the input was null or null. Alternatively try using an [expression](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/isnullop.html) within a case statement or (coalesce)[https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/coalesce.html]

```sql
CASE WHEN NAME IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE NAME END AS NAME
```

OR

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(NAME,'N/A') AS NAME
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways, like so:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, None), (2, None)], "id: int, value: string")
df.show()

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1| null|
|  2| null|
+---+-----+

df.na.fill("N/A", subset=["value"]).show()

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  N/A|
|  2|  N/A|
+---+-----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

df.withColumn("value", when(col("value").isNull(), "N/A")).show()

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|  N/A|
|  2|  N/A|
+---+-----+
```

Either option gives you the same result.